# How to check if class is exception class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I define a custom exception:

```
>>> class MyException(Exception):
>>>     pass
```

I create an exception instance:

```
>>> a = MyException()
```

I check if this is an exception. As expected, it is:

```
>>> isinstance(a, Exception)
True
```

But how do I check if the class is an exception class?

```
>>> myclass = MyException
>>> isinstance(myclass, Exception)
False
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can check if one class is inherited from other class by using [issubclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#issubclass) function

```
print issubclass(MyException, Exception)
```

result:

```
True
```

Comment: Cool. I need it to distinguish between object instances and sub-classes of Exception (for unit testing), and unfortunately `issubclass` fails for non-class objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking if `Exception` is under `__bases__`:

```
>>> my_class = MyException
>>> Exception in my_class.__bases__
True
```

Comment: Thanks, a bit hacky